# How to handle Multithreaded insertions with unique constrain in the database using JPA/Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss, synchronization, message-driven-bean

in a message driven bean i persist entries to lookup-table with unique entries. Basicly i create a select statement with the criteria api and if i don't find an entry, i create one.

Currently this code is running into mysql errors because in certain cases this entry creation (`em.persist(entry)`) would violate the unique constrain on my database. another instance of my mdb created the lookup entry after i didn't find it and before i could create it.

How can i handle this synchronization problem, so there still is only one entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [SELECT FOR UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) or ensure uniqueness differently (e.g. generating unique part of the entry inside Java).

Hibernate supports [pessimistic locks](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html) which I believe is just another name for the same thing.